# Static variable with templates

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I want to store some additional information about classname during inheritance:

```
#define CLASS_TO_STRING(name) #name

class IBase {};

template <typename T>
struct BaseManager
{
    static const char* MANAGER_TAG = CLASS_TO_STRING(T);
};

std::map<const char*, IBase*> mManagers;

template <typename T>
void addManager(BaseManager<T>* manager)
{
    mManagers[T::MANAGER_TAG] = manager;
}
```

So, when I call `addManager` with some object of type inherited from `BaseManager` I get an error that `BaseManager<TYPENAME>::MANAGER_TAG` is undefined. I understand the reason of the problem but can't understand how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `const char*` to `constexpr` but I am afraid all you will get from `CLASS_TO_STRING(T)` is `T` (at least g++ gives me T on output - and thats because preprocessor runs before compilation and template instantiation).

also instead of `T::MANAGER_TAG`, you should `BaseManager<T>::MANAGER_TAG`. And your BaseManager should inherit from IBase if :

```
mManagers[BaseManager<T>::MANAGER_TAG] = manager;
```

is supposed to work.

The reason you get your error is I suppose that in-class initialization of static data member, works only for const integral types.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from marcin_j's comment about in-class initialization (which works only in C++11 and for nonintegral types it requires constexpr), the real problem is this:

```
static const char* MANAGER_TAG = CLASS_TO_STRING(T);
```

When this line gets parsed by the preprocessor, CLASS_TO_STRING will turn T into the string literal "T". What's really going on here is that the preprocessor (the one performing macro substitution) has absolutely no idea of the template system and that T is a template parameter. You need a different approach here.